# Wordpress/WooCommerce: Changing SLUG for searchurl stops searching if the word is not "search" (via htaccess or functions.php)

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, woocommerce

Running a WooCommerce site and I can successfully change the search slug from ?s=xxx to /search/xxx using one of the following:

*htaccess:*

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} \\?s=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /search/%1/? [NC,R,L]
```

*functions.php*

```
function wp_change_search_url() {
    if ( is_search() && ! empty( $_GET['s'] ) ) {
        wp_redirect( home_url( "/search/" ) . urlencode( get_query_var( 's' ) ) );
        exit();
    }  
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wp_change_search_url' );
```

The problem occurs when i change the term "search" to something else. In my case swedish: /sok/. Then the searchfunction stops working and Worpdress says "Nothing found". I tried it on 3 servers, 3 themes, 0 plugins. Same result. If "search" is there it works fine, any other word it stops.

Any idea why?

Edit: The slug "find" also works. I've read all over the internet that people are having problems with this - No solutions seems to have been found though.

Comment: where do you do the change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll also need to change rewrite rules and flush permalinks after, so the process to change `search` slug to `sok` would be as follow:

Fist you start by creating proper redirect from the default search link to your targeted URL

```
function change_sok_url() {
    if ( is_search() && ! empty( $_GET['s'] ) ) {
        wp_redirect( home_url( "/sok/" ) . urlencode( get_query_var( 's' ) ) );
        exit();
    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'change_sok_url' );
```

Then change rewrite rules to match the new slug

```
function rewrite_sok_slug() {
    add_rewrite_rule(
        'sok(/([^/]+))?(/([^/]+))?(/([^/]+))?/?',
        'index.php?s=$matches[2]&paged=$matches[6]',
         'top'
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'rewrite_sok_slug' );
```

Then flush permalinks by saving permalink settings from http://yoursite.com/wp-admin/options-permalink.php, just click Save Changes, this should flush rewrite rules and apply the new structure.

**Note 1:** This is tested and working.

**Note 2:** No need for `.htaccess` changes.

Comment: Worked like a sharm. Do you have ny idea why my code only worked with search and find slug? Why would it actually work with those 2 but not sok?

Comment: I'm not sure, find should not work either unless defined somewhere, search however is the default slug, so it's working by default. Make sure to always flush permalinks on any URL structure change for your changes to take effect.

Comment: thank you kind sir for the quick reply and for the solution.